# Unable to fetch HTML content from mail in Lotus Notes, getMIMEEntity() returns a null even after setConvertMIME(false)

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-notes, document, lotus-domino

I am trying to read the HTML contents of a Document object(mail) as a part of my plug in development in Lotus Notes 9.

With this HTML content, we would like to create a file and send it as an attachment file in our query, so we can preserve the formatting, images, etc.

Even after  `session.setConvertMIME(false);` I still do not get the Mime entity when I call `doc.getMIMEEntity()`.

1. I have made preferences setting in Preferences>Mail>Internet

   Internet mail format to "HTML and plain text".
2. I have tried `doc.createMIMEEntity` and then tried to retrieve it
3. `mimePart = doc.getMIMEEntity("Body");`

When i right clicked on Incoming mails from outlook I was able to see multiple Body items, one of which contained the HTML part.However I was still not able to access it via `getMIMEEntity`.

The mails I created from lotus notes, do not have multiple Body items. When I receive the mails from Lotus Notes > Outlook and I inspect source in Outlook, I see it as HTML. So I assume there is a place where this conversion takes place.

```
ShelfSession.getInstance().localSession.setConvertMime(false);
MIMEEntity nMime = (MIMEEntity) doc.getMIMEEntity("Body");
```

I want the Mime part to be set to this variable so I can retrieve the content to form the HTML file.

Please help with any code suggestions or is there some Lotus notes setting that I have missed out on that is making the Mime variable always null?

Comment: Is mimePart null when you do 'doc.getMIMEEntity("Body")'?

Comment: Yes, it is a null I even tried getMIMEPart(); without arguments

Comment: Please update your question with more of the relevant source code

Comment: Does the message have $NoteHasNativeMIME set to 1 when you examine items in the Document Properties box? I'm guessing that it does not, and Dave Delay is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You said, "The mails I created from lotus notes, do not have multiple Body items."  This almost certainly means the Body item is stored as rich text instead of MIME.  You can confirm this by looking at the document properties in Notes.

You can use `document.convertToMIME()` to convert a Body item from Notes rich text to MIME.  Here's an example:

```
    MIMEEntity mimeEntity = null;
    Item item = document.getFirstItem("Body");
    if (item != null) {
        if (item.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT) {
            // Convert Notes rich text to MIME
            document.convertToMIME(Document.CVT_RT_TO_PLAINTEXT_AND_HTML, 0);
        } 
        mimeEntity = document.getMIMEEntity();
    }
```

I've adapted this example from some code in [MimeEntityHelper](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.commons/src/com/ibm/domino/commons/mime/MimeEntityHelper.java) from the XPages Extension Library.  I'd encourage you to take a look at that code for more context.  For example, you still need to call `session.setConvertMIME(false)` to avoid converting a document that is *already MIME* to rich text.  The `MimeEntityHelper` class uses both `session.setConvertMIME()` and `document.convertToMIME()` to control document conversions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions . However at the line       document.convertToMIME(Document.CVT_RT_TO_PLAINTEXT_AND_HTML, 0); i get this exception in the console :CD to MIME error (Process: ? (00005974:00000002), Database: CN=dewdfgwd01914/O=c4c!!mail\aramesh.nsf, Note: 00006B82): A database handle to a remote database cannot be used by more than one thread.
End CD to MIME Conversion(Process: ? (00005974:00000002), Database: CN=dewdfgwd01914/O=c4c!!mail\aramesh.nsf, Note: 00006B82)

Comment: Are you using the same `Database` instance in more than one thread? As the error message indicates, that's not supported. This is not a problem with `convertToMIME()`.

Comment: i will get back to you on that.i tried using the MimeEntityHelper from lines 85-89, i.e the else block and that has worked for me, well..to and extent. i have got my HTML body but without the styling information(using getContentAsText()). i need the entire HTML content to make a file (.html file) which will be further re rendered in our browser application.In the Outlook client i can simply retrieve the entire mail's HTML content using the HTMLbody property of the mail.Could you tell me where i can find the entire HTML with the styling information? Must i re-form it using the mime entity ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about an "HTML body but without the styling information."  I would need to see an example, but this sounds like a separate question.  StackOverflow is not designed for asking new questions in the comments section.  Can you post a separate question on this topic?

Comment: i have posted a new question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518245/entire-html-content-of-mail-not-accessible-and-original-mail-changes-to-rich-tex